# Count records entered in to multiple tables between date range

Tags: sql, sql-server

```
Table 1
--------
landrepairID pk
workshopID fk
Date

Table 2
--------
searepairID pk
workshopID fk
Date

Table 3
--------
airrepairID pk
workshopID fk
Date

Table 4
--------
workshopID pk
workshop name
```

I would like to retreve the amount of vehicles admitted to the garage in all three tables between two dates grouped by the workshop IDs.

as in, 
if dates are 1/1/2013 to 1/2/2013
the result should give as,

```
workshopID | count 
1             45
2             16
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
SELECT workshopid, 
       Count(1) AS countall
FROM   (SELECT workshopid 
        FROM   table1 
        WHERE  date BETWEEN '1/1/2013' AND '1/2/2013' 
        UNION ALL 
        SELECT workshopid 
        FROM   table2 
        WHERE  date BETWEEN '1/1/2013' AND '1/2/2013' 
        UNION ALL 
        SELECT workshopid 
        FROM   table3 
        WHERE  date BETWEEN '1/1/2013' AND '1/2/2013') as all_data 
GROUP  BY workshopid
```

Comment: i get this error ->The multi-part identifier "table4.workshopid" could not be bound... any idea about this ?

Comment: There is no table4 in my query. Can you post what you have tried?

Answer (score 0):

i ran into this issue myself and this is the solution i came up with:

```
<form action="" method="post" name="submit">
<input type="date" name="begin"/>
<input type="date" name="end"/>
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit"/>
</form>
<?php
error_reporting(0);
$start = strtotime($_POST['begin']);
$end = strtotime($_POST['end']);
 $con=mysqli_connect("localhost","user","password","dbname");
// Check connection
if (mysqli_connect_errno())
{
echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
 }
$result = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT user, SUM(1) FROM processed WHERE `date` BETWEEN FROM_UNIXTIME($start) AND FROM_UNIXTIME($end) GROUP BY first_name  ;" );

echo "<table border='1' class='data'>
<tr>

 <th>First Name</th>
<th>Last Name</th>
<th>Total Processed</th>
</tr>";

while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
 {
 echo "<tr>";
 echo "<td>" . $row['first_name '] . "</td>";
 echo "<td>" . $row['last_name '] . "</td>";
 echo "<td>" . $row['numb'] . "</td>";
 echo "</tr>";
 }
echo "</table>";


mysqli_close($con);

?>
```

i don't know how much this will help you out but i set it up so that you could actually select the dates you wanted instead of having hard values in your code.

Comment: yes, i can get the idea by this. but its mysql ya? will FROM_UNIXTIME work on mssql or is there any similar functions to it ?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
DECLARE @DateFrom DATE, @DateTo DATE
SELECT  @DateFrom = '1/1/2013', @DateTo = '1/2/2013' 
SELECT workshopid, Cnt 
FROM   (SELECT workshopid, COUNT(*) AS Cnt
        FROM   table1 
        WHERE  date BETWEEN @DateFrom AND @DateTo
        UNION ALL 
        SELECT workshopid, COUNT(*) AS Cnt
        FROM   table2
        WHERE  date BETWEEN @DateFrom AND @DateTo
        UNION ALL 
        SELECT workshopid, COUNT(*) AS Cnt
        FROM   table3 
        WHERE  date BETWEEN @DateFrom AND @DateTo
) aggregated
```